# Object constructor as function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, functional-programming

Say I have a simple Javascript object:

```
var Thing = function (data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

Would there be a shorter way of doing something like the following?:

```
var makeThing = function(data) { return new Thing(data); };
var things = $.map(array, makeThing);
```

Comment: @RobG: I strongly suspect alias for `jQuery`; the OP is invoking [jQuery.map](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).

Comment: Indeed, it is jQuery or Zepto's `$` alias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest I can see is

```
var things = $.map(data, function(x) { return new Thing(x); })
```

as a trivial compression.

If you are sure you can do newer JS,

```
var things = data.map(function(x) { return new Thing(x); })
```

is shorter still.

Comment: But is it possible to reference the constructor of the object as a function? Something like: `data.map(Thing.constructor)`

Comment: `Thing` *is* the constructor function. However, you won't get a new object from it without the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). JavaScript works a little bit like Objective C in this regard - when you do `[[Thing alloc] init]`, with two different functions for allocation and initialisation of the object. `new` is allocating a new object; `Thing` is setting it up (and is termed "constructor"). You can invoke the "constructor" on anything, but it will just end up tacking extra properties on an existing object.